# Getting error unable to get local issuer certificate in Bruno

Tags: salesforce, bruno

I am using Bruno and trying to get Auth Token.

When I am sending the Post request, Getting below error:

```
Error invoking remote method 'send-http-request': Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

How can we resolve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to **Collections** menu and Click on **Preferences**:

[image]

Uncheck **SSL/TLS Certificate Verification**:

[image]

Click **Save**

Now if you send the request again it will not verify the certificate and request will go through.